# How to achieve single domain > multiple stores > different products and prices per store

Tags: magento2, product, price, multistore

I need to build out multiple Magento 'stores' on a single website, with each 'store' representing a unique partner who offers a different combination of products from our global catalog.

For example, if our global catalog contains 10 products [p1,p2,p3,...p10], and we want the following configuration...

- "Partner A" store at "//domain.xyz/store/partner-a" only offers products p1, p3, p5, p7, and p9.
- "Partner B" store at "//domain.xyz/store/partner-b" only offers products p2, p4, p6, and p8.
- "Partner C" store at "//domain.xyz/store/partner-c" offers all 10 products, but with different retail prices from partners A and B.

...is this possible with Magento 2.x?

My current overall understanding of Magento 2.x is:

1. Multiple stores on one website is possible.
2. Each product can have a different price per store if we define our price scope as 'website' rather than 'global'.
3. Each store can feature a different (but not mutually exclusive) list of products if we set each store up with a new 'root category'
   defining that store's available products.

Am I off-base? If so, are there any proven ways, or even easier ways, to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Its possible here is the docs from magento setup multiple store

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

Comment: @AmanAlam Thank you! I think that certainly addresses Question #1. Specifically speaking, do you know of documentation that explicitly explains how to achieve what I'm asking in Questions 2 & 3 above? Thank you, again.